# Does Azure IoT Edge module receive a twin patch when it starts up?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

Is it normal for an IoT Edge Module to receive a twin patch everytime it starts up?

Imagine this scenario:

- IoT edge is configured in an On-prem VM
- A property is added into example_module's twin desired properties
- example_module receives a patch and sets its environmental variables based on the patch received and reports back the properties
- example_module crashes due to an unrelated issue and restarts

Does example_module receive a patch when it starts up after the crash?

Comment: the twin desired properties are stored in the cloud and are sent to the module upon startup to ensure that the module's configuration matches the [desired state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-1.4). could tell which SDK you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what happens.

The scenario you described the `example_module` restarts after a crash, it would receive a patch containing the latest desired properties. The IoT Edge runtime maintains the desired properties state for each module, and when a module starts or restarts, it syncs up its state with the desired properties from the `edgeAgent`. This behaviour ensures the module is always in sync with the desired state defined in its module twin, even after crashes or restarts.